# Auto Login with cookies, Angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement auto login feature on my Angular app. I create the cookie when the user logs in. I am able to retrieve the cookie and the correct stored contents when reloading the page.

What I'm trying to do is log the user in automatically upon reloading the page.

Here is how app.component.ts:

```
 export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    private cookieService: CookiesService,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileService.getCachedProfile();
    this.profileService.newToken.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.submit(data.sub, data.pwd);
    });
  }

  submit(username: string, pword: string) {
    this.loginService.signIn(username, pword);
    this.loginService.currentloginAttemp.subscribe(data => {
      if (data == true) {

        this.profileService.getProfile();
        this.loggedOff = false;
        $('.intro-header').css({'flex-direction': 'row'});
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/tour');


      }
      this.loggedin = data;
    });

    (async () => {

      await this.delay(500);
      this.profileService.newProfileObj.subscribe(dataProfile => {
        $('.profile-icon').css({'background-image': 'url("' + dataProfile[0].profileimage + '")'});
      });
    })();
  }
}
```

Here is my profileService account that first makes a post request to get the cached profile.

```
  getCachedProfile() {
    const jwtCookie = this.cookie.getUserCookie();
    if (!(jwtCookie === '')) {
      const formdata = new FormData();
      formdata.append('jwt', jwtCookie);

      this.http.post<Token>(this.getCachedProfileURL, formdata, {responseType: 'json'}).subscribe(res => {
        if (res.sub === 'Expired') {
          console.log('Token has expired.');
        } else {
          this.currToken.next(res);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

the token is then added to the BehaviorSubject currToken. After that (referring  back to app.component.ts, I subscribe to the Observer of currToken)

```
this.profileService.newToken.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.submit(data.sub, data.pwd);
});
```

Removing this.submit: console.log actually kicks off twice. The first time it logs **data** I get a null. The second it logs data I am able to view data.sub and data.pwd.  Why console.log is happening twice, I'm not sure.

But because it happens twice and the first time is null, I'm getting an error  when I run the method this.submit. The error happens beccause data.sub and data.pwd are null. Makes sense.

Main Objective:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------v
So how do I subscribe to data first before sending the data through the method this.submit?

EDIT: Also when I subscribe to my Observer, it seems that I'm subscribing twice. Everything inside the subscribe method executes twice.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you need to unsubscribe the behaviorsubject in OnDestroy. Here is the code

```
private unsub;

ngOnInit() {
    this.unsub = this.profileService.newToken.subscribe(data => {
      this.submit(data.sub, data.pwd);
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.unsub){
       this.unsub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure. Instead of using a Behavior Subject for the token. I'm using a Subject and this fixed problem.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of the behavior subject constructor is the default value of the subject value. I think using a replay subject with buffer size 1 is the best solution